# Backpack 4.0 base configuration key "passwords"

Tags: laravel-6, laravel-backpack

This is my first time using Backpack and I have a question about the base.php Backpack config. One of the keys there is called `passwords` and it has this random string value as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

For the life of me I don't know what that means. The only thing I know so far is that the Forgot Password form submits to a page with the following error.

```
InvalidArgumentException
Password resetter [c45#$%TCC)*$%tc;pvctHJ^] is not defined.
```

When I set the `passwords` config value to null, the form works but the Reset Password link from the email shows a link like:

`<mydomain>/password/reset?token=a67b566284a8415923f799682a50509cfd6ae11e4ea0f6e3026271a5446c1f61&email=xxx`

instead of:

`<mydomain>/password/reset/a67b566284a8415923f799682a50509cfd6ae11e4ea0f6e3026271a5446c1f61?email=xxx`

So it is not matching the route defined in Backpack. But I guess that is another topic.

For now I just need to understand what the `passwords` config does and why is the value set like it currently is. Can anyone please explain?

Answer (score 0):

That config should hold the **name of the password broker** that Backpack uses inside the Authentication.

It should NOT be gibberish, but the actual name of the password broker to be used. By default that's `backpack` as you can [see in our demo](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/demo/blob/master/config/backpack/base.php#L223). If commented out, it will use the same password broker that the stock Laravel Auth uses - as explained in the comment. **I recommend you write `backpack` there - that should fix it for you.**

This value should only be changed when you want to customize the authentication, and have mixed auth for users and admins, things like that. It uses Laravel's authentication, which is unnecessarily complicated if you ask me, but that's where the password broker concept is from.